# Can't boot up my laptop after upgrade to (K)ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, kubuntu, 13.04

Yesterday I did a '*do-release-upgrade*' from my laptop (HP DV-6) running flawlessly Kubuntu 12.10, to 13.04. Upgrade process ended up with no errors.

But now, when laptop boots normally, hangs during graphical login. Sounds it has some issue when enabling network interfaces, since they are not working at all while at the boot prompt.

Alternatively, **if I start in recovery mode**, and choose "resume" in the first choice list, it boots up, logins, and works normally, with working network too.
Can't understand the differences between two boot options so as to compromise the functionality of the system...

I also upgrade my desktop computer (a quad-core AMD based PC) from 12.10 to 13.04, with no issues at all.

Comment: have you installed any graphics driver manually (using run file)? you need to do that again if so.

Answer (score 0):

during graphical login press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, text login should appear

- login
- `cat ~/.xsession-errors` the last lines might be interesting
- `mv ~/.xsession-errors ~/kde-bug.log` just to have a copy of the log
- `mv .kde .kde-tmp` backup old KDE configuration
- `sudo reboot`

past the content of `~/kde-bug.log` e.g. to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and send us the link